# VLC Subtitles are cut off/looping around?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, subtitles

I have a .mkv file with .srt subtitles.

For some reason, sometimes the last letter of the top row of subtitles gets cut in half, and the half that gets cut off appears at the front of the sentence?

See image for example.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: I can only glibly answer "with a subs file editor". I don't read SE Asian text at all, but in my experience with English subs errors, it can always be blamed directly on a timing or composition error on the part of the original subs encoder.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I have absolutely 0 experience doing anything with subtitles, could you perhaps tell me what I'd be looking for in order to shift things over a bit? I have Aegis sub downloaded but don't know what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what the error will be. I'd compare to a file you know works well & try to spot the difference.

Comment: Cool thanks! Will do that!